# Finding the closest point in a set in o(n) time

Tags: algorithms, nearest-neighbour

Suppose I have a set S which is a set of points in a 3D plane. Given point P, is it possible to construct a data structure A such that the closest point to P in A can be found in o(n) time? My assumption would be to use a Kd-tree or an octree, which I think would take O(log_3(n)) to find. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search, [tag:nearest-neighbor]

Comment: `a 3D plane` can you elaborate on this? I expect planes to be 2D - does the orientation in 3D space matter, can't it just be rotated?